# If $I$ is a fractional ideal, $II^{-1}$ is an integral ideal ? (Dedekind ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

My question is pretty simple, I don't figure out why, if $I$ is a fractional ideal of $A$ (where $A$ is a Dedekind ring), $II^{-1}$ (at the moment I do not have proved that $II^{-1} = A$) should be an integral ideal of $A$ ? Actually, the fact that $\lambda II^{-1} \subset II^{-1}$ is pretty obvious, but I don't succeed to prove that $II^{-1}$ is a subgroup for $+$.

Someone could help me, please ?

Thank you !

Comment: For fractional ideals, $IJ$ is the additive group generated by products of elements in $I$ with elements in $J$, by definition.

Comment: Ok, everything is clear now ! Thank you.